# VIBER PHP file_put_contents save all inputs

Tags: php, viber, viber-bot

I have Viber bot. I want to save my id's. But `file_put_content` save all data. I just want `user.id`.
And also it's repeating ids.  So I want just to save `user.ids` and not to repeat them.

```php
file_put_contents("azer1.txt", file_get_contents("php://input"));
$viber = file_get_contents("azer1.txt");
$viber = JSON_decode($viber);
```

Comment: It depends on what is in `php://input`. Probably you'll need to read it, iterate and assign to another variable. But looks like it has nothing to do with Viber.

Answer (score 0):

you can read `php://input` with array

`php://input` to arrray

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data); //your array
```

be carefull php not has as such `JSON_decode($viber);` method,
must be lovercase as such `json_decode()`